# How do I update a nested model in pydantic with mongodb and fast api

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

My Models:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(default_factory=uuid.UUID, alias="_id")
    post_count: int
    last_awarded: int
    points: int
    characters: list[Character]

class CharacterUpdate(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    type: Optional[str] = None
    xp: Optional[int] = None
```

My FastAPI Route:

```
@router.put("/{id}/{name}", response_description="Update a character", response_model=Character)
def update_character(id: int, name:str, request: Request, char: CharacterUpdate = Body(...)):
    char = {k: v for k, v in char.model_dump().items() if v is not None}
    if len(char) >= 1:
        update_result = request.app.database["users"].update_one(
            {"_id": id, "characters.name": name}, {"$set": char}
        )
```

My data:

```
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "post_count": 0,
  "last_awarded": 0,
  "points": 0,
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "Person 1",
      "type": "Character",
      "xp": 900
    },
    {
      "name": "Person 2",
      "type": "NPC",
      "xp": 900
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to pass this into the route:

```
curl -X 'PUT' \
  'http://localhost:8000/user/12345/Person%201' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "Person 3"
}'
```

I tried the above and expected that the dict with the character named "Person 1" would update to have a name of "Person 3" without removing the "type" and "xp" of that dict. Instead, the characters list had the elements of the request added to it like:

```
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "post_count": 0,
  "last_awarded": 0,
  "points": 0,
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "Person 1",
      "type": "Character",
      "xp": 900
    },
    {
      "name": "Person 2",
      "type": "NPC",
      "xp": 900
    },
    "name": "Person 3",
  ]
}
```

I want this route to be dynamic in that if I put a request to change type and xp, it will leave name alone etc.